# Creating a probability distribution using Piecewise

Tags: probability-or-statistics, piecewise

The following "Manipulate" shows the behaviour of functions that I hope, if collected according to the rules shown further down, can be transformed into a probability distribution:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    {Plot[(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2), {P, x/(1 + f), x}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red}], 
     Plot[(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), {P, x, (f + x)/(1 + f)}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Blue}], 
     Plot[((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2), {P, x, -(x/(-1 + f))}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Green}], 
     Plot[(f + P - f P - x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), {P, (f - x)/(-1 + f), x}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Black}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 25}}], 
  {f, 0, 1}, 
  {x, 0, 1}]
```

The rules for collecting the distribution are:

For "Green":

```
((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2)
x < P <= -(x/(-1 + f)) < 1/2
```

For "Blue":

```
(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2)
1/2 <= x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f))
```

For "Red":

```
(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2)
x/(1 + f) <= P <= x <= 1/2
```

For "Black":

```
(f + P - f P - x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2)
1/2 < (f - x)/(-1 + f) <= P <= x
```

I have made the following attempt, but I suspect I may be doing something wrong. If you exmine the above `Manipulate` expression, and `Plot` the result of the `Piecewise` procedure below, I cannot find much connection.

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
  FullSimplify[
    ProbabilityDistribution[
      {"CF", 
       Piecewise[
         {{((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2), x < P <= -(x/(-1 + f)) < 1/2}, 
          {(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), 1/2 <= x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f))}, 
          {(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2), x < x/(1 + f) <= P <= x <= 1/2}, 
          {(f + P - f P - x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), 1/2 < (f - x)/(-1 + f) <= P <= x}}, 
         0]}, 
      {x, 0, 1}, 
      Assumptions -> 0 <= P <= 1]]

Show[
  {With[{f = 3/4}, Plot[-(1/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2)), {P, 0, 1}]], 
   With[{f = 3/4}, Plot[1/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), {P, 0, 1}]], 
   With[{f = 3/4}, Plot[-(1/(f^2 P^2)), {P, 0, 1}]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-10, 100}}]
```

Here is the plot of the above

[image]

and here is one from the `Manipulate` expression.

[image]

#### Edit

JimB requested some clarification.

While `Manipulate` apparently shows two distributions, what is really happening is a switching, so to speak. For values of $x$ between 0 and 1/2 the functions for "Red" and "Green" are applicable, while for values of $x$ above 1/2 "Blue" and "Black" are applicable. Also, $f$ is a parameter of the distribution, effectively restricting its variance. Note that $P$ is the random variable (on the horizontal axis), not $x$ and not $f$.  should have made that clearer.

So, there is some complication, because the distribution I am looking to obtain must account for the described switching.

Comment: I think you have a typo: `(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), {1/2 <= x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f))}` should be `{(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), 1/2 <= x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f))}`. Notice the position of the parenthesis

Comment: The typo is fixed in the latest.

Comment: " I cannot find much connection."  What do you mean by that?  Please be more explicit about your issue.  (Also, for *Mathematica* 10.4, I don't have a "CF" option for `ProbabilityDistribution`.  Is that something in a newer version of *Mathematica*?)

Comment: JimB, first the "CF" probably shows my ignorance; I thought this was a name field. Second, by no connection I mean that I was expecting to be output a formula or formulas that resembled the distribution illustrated by the Manipulate chart. I was not expecting something that could be negative and I was not expecting a steadily rising graph. In short I was expecting a distribution closed by the x axis.

Comment: From the `Manipulate` code it looks like you have two random variables but your expectation (personal expectation not statistical expectation) is that a single formula should result.  Are `p` and `F` parameters?  Again, please be more explicit.

Comment: JimB, I will clarify in the text.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I'm still confused (it happens a lot these days). I'll stop after this comment. From your clarification "red" and "green" are applicable when $0\leq P\leq 1/2$ and "blue" and "black" are applicable when $P>1/2$. So why do the "red" and "green" lines go from 0.5 to greater than 1 and the "blue" and "black" lines only range from 0.5 to 0.8? For the particular values of f and x in the last figure (and I assume x is also a parameter but you haven't stated that) should we only be seeing the "blue" and "black" line segments because P>1/2?

Comment: JimB, No, the mistake was mine. I wrongly stated that switching goes on as $P$ moves across 0.5. The right statement is that switching occurs as the parameter $x$ moves across 0.5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82946/discussion-between-jimb-and-user120911).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to put everything into a single function.  This will not give you a symbolic function in terms of `x` and `f` but such a function is so complicated/busy-looking that I don't see how it would be useful.

```
g[x_, f_] := Module[{gg, const, P},
  gg = Piecewise[{
     {((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2), x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f)) && x <= 1/2},
     {(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2),    x/(1 + f) <= P <= x <= 1/2},
     {(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), x <= P <= (f + x)/(1 + f) && 1/2 < x <= 1},
     {(f + P - f P - x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), (f - x)/(-1 + f) <= P <= x && 1/2 < x <= 1}}, 0];
  const = Integrate[gg, {P, 0, 1}];
  gg = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[gg/const]];
  ProbabilityDistribution[gg, {P, 0, 1}]]

Manipulate[\[ScriptCapitalD] = g[x, f];
 Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], P], {P, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
 {{x, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Complicated pdf]

Answer (score 0):

I venture the following solution:

Since the distribution switches between consisting of different segments of four distinct functions at $x = 0.5$, it makes sense to examine the case below and above that point.

The switching pattern is as follows:

$x < 0.5$:

```
((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2)
x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f)) 

(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2)
x/(1 + f) <= P <= x
```

$x > 0.5$:

```
(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2)
x <= P <= -(x/(-1 + f))

(f + P - f P - x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2)
(f - x)/(-1 + f) <= P <= x
```

My solution is therefore:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]A = ProbabilityDistribution[{"PDF", Piecewise[{{((-1 + f) P + x)/(f^2 P^2), x <=  P <= -(x/(-1 + f))}, {(P + f P - x)/(f^2 P^2), x/(1 + f) <=  P <=  x}}, 0]}, {P, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < x <= 1/2, 0 < f < 1}]

\[ScriptCapitalD]B = ProbabilityDistribution[{"PDF", Piecewise[{{(f - P - f P + x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), x <= P <= (f + x)/(1 + f)}, {(f + P - f P - x)/(f^2 (-1 + P)^2), (f - x)/(-1 + f) <= P <= x}}, 0]}, {P, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {1/2 <=  x <  1, 0 < f < 1}]
```

Comment: Almost there.  You'll need to use `Method->"Normalize"` so that the PDF's integrate to 1.  Or you'll need to include the appropriate constant as you define the `ProbabilityDistribution`.